# Issue when using PNGs into CToolBar object

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm trying to insert a `CImageList` into a `CToolBar` object called `m_wndUtilBar`. I add all images using the code below:

```
CImageList imageList;
CBitmap bitmap;
COLORREF crMask = RGB(192, 192, 192);

CSize button, button_img;
button.cx = 39; 
button.cy = 39; 
button_img.cx = 32; 
button_img.cy = 32;
m_wndUtilBar.SetSizes(button, button_img);

imageList.Create(button_img.cx, button_img.cy, ILC_COLOR32 | ILC_MASK, 18, 1);

LoadBitmapFromPNG(IDB_PNG_UP, bitmap);
imageList.Add(&bitmap, crMask);
bitmap.Detach();
.
.
. // adding more images into the list
.
```

And then I add the list into the object as below:

```
m_wndUtilBar.GetToolBarCtrl().SetImageList(&imageList);
imageList.Detach();
```

All images I used are resources included in the project not as bitmaps but as PNGs (I say it because I think that is the issue is there).

Once I run the application everything works fine. All images are displayed and the buttons work correctly. However, when I disable one of those buttons, the image of this button appears as enabled (without that typical gray disabled mask) and I don't know why.

Can anybody help me? I don't know what to do to apply the disable effect to an image of a disabled button.

**UPDATE 1**

I see that the disable effect only appears on the borders of the images, so I sopose that the effect is applied, However, this effect is not applied inside the PNG.

Comment: Color mapping is done automatically in `CToolBar::LoadToolBar`, it has to change `RGB(192,192,192)` to dialog background color etc. You are overriding all that, so you have to do it yourself when PNG file is loaded. But I am not sure if this is going to look good for high color PNG files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to supply a png graphic for the disabled state as well.

From the documentation:

[Using Image Lists in a Toolbar Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/using-image-lists-in-a-toolbar-control?view=vs-2019)

you need to use SetDisabledImageList(), and SetHotImageList() for stuff like that.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean... Are you saying that I have to duplicate all PNGs, applying to those images a disabled effect, add them into the image list and changing each image of each button in runtime?

Comment: Thanks for the information. However, what I don't understand is why I have to apply two `CImageList`. When I use bitmaps instead of PNG, the `CToolBar` automatically applies the disable effect whitout using the `DisableImageList`. This automatization doesn'¡t work with PNGs?

Comment: It shouldn't matter if you load it as a PNG file or a BMP file - a bitmap is a bitmap.  As a test, you might try loading them from PNG or BMP files via the respective calls; but if you are loading them as icons via the icon call, they may behave differently.

Comment: Ah.  Your edit says that if you load a bitmap from a PNG, it doesn't do the disabled effect.  Perhaps alpha data is being stored in the bitmap, accounting for the diff.